# How to add vertical space before `hline` in `array`

Tags: spacing, arrays

I am trying to format the following table with more space below the horizontal lines.

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        i & (266)_i & [266]_i\\[3pt]
        \hline
        1   & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega                 \\
        2   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2                  \\
        3   & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1                  \\
        4   & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1}     &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1}                      \\
        5   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2                   \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots        \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

I have tried replacing `hline` by `\hline\noalign{\vskip 3pt}` but this leaves a vertical break in the borders `{|c|c|c|}`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution based on the `cellspace` package, which defines `minimal` vertical spacing at the top or bottom of cells in columns with qualifier prefixed with the letter `S`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, amsmath}

\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
    \begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{|Sc|>{$}Sc<{$}|c|}
        \hline
 i & (266)_i & [266]_i\\
        \hline
        1 & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega \\
        2 & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2 \\
        3 & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1 \\
        4 & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1} & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} \\
        5 & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 \\[-6pt]
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two versions (the second is better, in my opinion)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

First version with vertical rules
\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
i      & (266)_i                   & [266]_i \\
\hline
1      & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega \\
2      & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2      \\
3      & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1      \\
4      & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1}     & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1}          \\
5      & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2                               \\
\vdots & \vdots                    & \vdots                                                  \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
and the second version without them
\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{6pt}
\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[-2pt]
i      & (266)_i                   & [266]_i \\
\midrule
1      & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega \\
2      & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2      \\
3      & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1      \\
4      & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1}     & \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1}          \\
5      & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2                               \\
\vdots & \vdots                    & \vdots                                                  \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use \extrarowheight from the array package if you want the space everywhere. For more space in one row you could either insert an empty line and then get back a bit, of use some strut, e.g. a \vphantom equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \extrarowheight5pt
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        i & (266)_i & [266]_i\\[3pt]
        \hline
        1   & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega                 \\
        2   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2                  \\
        3   & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1                  \\
        4   & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1}     &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1}                      \\
        5   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2                   \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots        \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        i & (266)_i & [266]_i\\[3pt]
        \hline &&\\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+5pt]
        1   & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega                 \\
        2   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2                  \\
        3   & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1                  \\
        4   & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1}     &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1}                      \\
        5   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2                   \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots        \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        i & (266)_i & [266]_i\\[3pt]
        \hline 
        \vphantom{2^{2^{2+1^{2^{1^{1}}}}}}%
        1   & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega                 \\
        2   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2                  \\
        3   & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1                  \\
        4   & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1}     &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1}                      \\
        5   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2                   \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots        \\
        \hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With good old mdwtab it is simple:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|Mc|Mc|}
    \hlx{hv}
i & (266)_i & [266]_i\\[3pt]
    \hlx{hvv}
1   & 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + \omega                 \\
2   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 2                  \\
3   & 4^{4^{4+1}} + 4^{4+1} + 1 &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1} + 1                  \\
4   & 5^{5^{5+1}} + 5^{5+1}     &   \omega^{\omega^{\omega+1}} + \omega^{\omega+1}                      \\
5   & 3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2 &   3^{3^{3+1}} + 3^{3+1} + 2                   \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots        \\
    \hlx{h}
    \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Note: `mdwtab` is not compatible with `colortbl`, i.e. cells, columns or row can not be colored.